# android mono: using List<T> instead of ArrayAdapter to make use of the Contains method

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

My concern is mainly to use **Contains** method of List (I think the best way to do checking).

**Controls:** Spinner, EditText and Button(for checking)

In my resources(String.xml) I created a string-array of name = "Fruits".

In my Activity1.cs I also created an ArrayAdapter to populate the items of my string-array and assigned it to my spinner.adapter object.

```
var spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.Fruits, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;
```

**Note:** The text found on the EditText control is equal to the selected item on the spinner control **BUT** I also allow the user to enter it manually.

**Questions:**

1. If this is possible, how can I convert ArrayAdapter to List type. (**My main purpose** is to make use of the Contain method in w/c I am checking the inputted data from EditText if found on the List)
2. Is there any other way to check data out from the string-array resource? (**Note:** I don't want to use any loop just to check only 1 item on the program if it exist. Just let .net do the rest for me.)

Answer (score 2):

One easy way would be to just load the string array yourself into memory and check there:

```
string[] fruits = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.Fruits);
var containsOrange = fruits.Contains("orange");
```

Make sure you have the `System.Linq` namespace included in order to get the `Contains()` method.